# Не привзывается контекст вызова в React.js

Tags: reactjs, jsx, create-react-app

Заранее извиняюсь за такой банальный вопрос, я новичок в реакте.
я пытаюсь вызвать фугкцию при клике на импортированную кнопку, но функция не вызывается. Но если эту функцию добавить  в сам компонент, то она работает. как можно привязать контекст вызова кнопки к классу App?

вот код файла App.js:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
class App extends Component {
    state = { 
        items: 'Новая задача'
    }
    NewTask () {
        alert(1)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <HeaderWrapper>
                    <MainHeader />
                </HeaderWrapper>
                <Wrapper>
                    <AddTaskInput />
                    <Button onClick={this.NewTask} text="Add" />
                </Wrapper>
                <TasksWrapper>
                    <Task taskName={this.state.items}/>
                </TasksWrapper>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

вот код файла Button.js:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
class Button extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <StyledButton>{this.props.text}</StyledButton>
        );
    }
}
export default Button;
```

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант #1:

```
class App extends Component {
   state = { 
        items: 'Новая задача'
    }
    NewTask () {
        alert(1)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <HeaderWrapper>
                    <MainHeader />
                </HeaderWrapper>
                <Wrapper>
                    <AddTaskInput />
                    <Button onClick={() => this.NewTask()} text="Add" />
                </Wrapper>
                <TasksWrapper>
                    <Task taskName={this.state.items}/>
                </TasksWrapper>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Вариант #2:

```
class App extends Component {
   state = { 
        items: 'Новая задача'
    }
    NewTask () {
        alert(1)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <HeaderWrapper>
                    <MainHeader />
                </HeaderWrapper>
                <Wrapper>
                    <AddTaskInput />
                    <Button onClick={this.NewTask.bind(this)} text="Add" />
                </Wrapper>
                <TasksWrapper>
                    <Task taskName={this.state.items}/>
                </TasksWrapper>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Вариант #2 (Best Practice):

```
class App extends Component {
   constructor() {
       this.state = { 
          items: 'Новая задача'
       }

       this.NewTask = this.NewTask.bind(this);
   } 
    NewTask () {
        alert(1)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <HeaderWrapper>
                    <MainHeader />
                </HeaderWrapper>
                <Wrapper>
                    <AddTaskInput />
                    <Button onClick={this.NewTask} text="Add" />
                </Wrapper>
                <TasksWrapper>
                    <Task taskName={this.state.items}/>
                </TasksWrapper>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант №4(Best practice), используйте `unbound function` (`arrow function`):

```
class App extends Component {
    state = { 
      items: 'Новая задача'
    }

    newTask = () => alert(1)

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <HeaderWrapper>
                    <MainHeader />
                </HeaderWrapper>
                <Wrapper>
                    <AddTaskInput />
                    <Button onClick={this.newTask} text="Add" />
                </Wrapper>
                <TasksWrapper>
                    <Task taskName={this.state.items}/>
                </TasksWrapper>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```